# Take previously viewed products only

Tags: sql, postgresql

I store events such as view, cart, purchase etc. for my products. Now I would like to take only products which were viewed before purchase.

I can't come up with an idea how to do it in omptimal way.

Here is my table structure below

| id | user_id | product_id | event_type | event_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a113a813-10e1-4e4f-88a4-4eaf1be1b5af | 9bf46f1a-51df-44c0-8875-fe6d8d35d503 | 643 | view | 2020-12-21 12:19:13 |
| 581746f3-ac5c-4331-87fe-1a33ea526b5f | 9bf46f1a-51df-44c0-8875-fe6d8d35d503 | 643 | purchase | 2020-12-21 12:19:32 |
| c4cf64b5-fdfd-4604-b1d8-3296d6da5a3a | f8cb84e7-b942-43e6-a7ba-48e8f8d2331e | 730 | view | 2020-12-21 13:14:06 |
| 7d22b26d-b3d0-4f1e-b615-2816dbd96785 | f8cb84e7-b942-43e6-a7ba-48e8f8d2331e | 730 | purchase | 2020-12-21 13:14:42 |
| cb14e71c-982a-43ca-8f01-82223b3de4e5 | 04cfed3c-0356-4cc2-91b9-0a6833fdd44d | 728 | purchase | 2020-12-21 13:44:29 |

Edit:
I use PostgreSQL 9

Comment: 'I can't come up with an idea how to do it in omptimal way.' - so you have a way but you are not sure if it is optimal ? please add what you have.

Comment: @P.Salmon I was wondering on use subquery in the last resort

Comment: If your idea is suboptimal, we may be able to turn it into optimal if you share it.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9? Are you sure? This version is from 2010 and is EOL'd since 2015. I sincerely suggest you to upgrade your system asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the `event_type` value before the last one.

Here is what the query might look like

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    user_id, 
    product_id, 
    event_type, 
    event_time 
FROM (
    SELECT 
       id, user_id, product_id, event_type, event_time,
       LAG(event_type) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, product_id ORDER BY event_time ASC) AS prev_event
    FROM data
) d WHERE event_type = 'purchase' AND prev_event = 'view'
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4b2b8a8099b5d4815122d4c413619d60)

As per @siwymilek comment to support any number of different events between *view* and *purchase* `event_type` value it is not even needed to analyze it's previous value, technically it's needed to check if a row with `event_type` value *view* exists for particular `user_id` and `product_id` with `event_time` value less than with *purchase*.

And a query would be like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, product_id)
    LAST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, product_id) AS last_id, 
    user_id, 
    product_id, 
    LAST_VALUE(event_time) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, product_id) AS last_event_time
FROM data d
WHERE event_type = 'purchase' AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM data 
    WHERE user_id = d.user_id 
          AND product_id = d.product_id 
          AND event_type = 'view'
          AND event_time < d.event_time
)
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=35e927e0ace6b70f211e5d7ca6c5d37e)

Comment: but it won't work if there will be additional event in the middle of view and purchase (eg. cart)

Comment: @siwymilek Indeed, additional event_types are breaking this solution ([db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=f263f4e16294ef039d8a46f9a2f971e4))

Answer (score 0):

I propose to make 2 subqueries to get the first interesting events and then join the product_id and filter by `view` < `purchase` to get the result:

```sql
with
     views as (select min(event_time) first_view, product_id from test where event_type = 'view' group by product_id),
     purchases as (select min(event_time) first_purchase, product_id from test where event_type = 'purchase' group by product_id)
select * from views join purchases on views.product_id = purchases.product_id where views.first_view < purchases.first_purchase;
```

See this [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=07704c69eb845f013a5fc428d754d3d9). (Also works well if there are additional event_types in the table, see @
siwymilek's comment)